# Include header file from subdirectorie cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

Given this tree:

```
Project
| CmakeLists.txt
| File1
|| CMakeLists.txt
|| include 
|||file1.h
|| src
|||file1.cpp
|||main.cpp
| File2
|| CMakeLists.txt
|| include 
|||file2.h
|| src
|||file2.cpp
|||main.cpp
| Core
|| core.h
|| CMakeLists.txt
|build
||"build files"
```

I would like to link the core.h to file1.h and file2.h, but what I currently have does not appear to work
PROJECT CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.7)

project(file1)
project(file2)

add_subdirectory(file1)
add_subdirectory(file2)
add_subdirectory(core)

set_target_properties(core PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

target_include_directories(file1 PUBLIC core)
target_include_directories(file2 PUBLIC core)
target_link_directories(file1 PRIVATE Core/)
target_link_directories(file2 PRIVATE Core/)
target_link_libraries(file1 core)
target_link_libraries(file2 core)
```

FILE1 CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.7)

project (file1)

set(SOURCES src/file1.cpp src/main.cpp)

add_executable(file1 ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(file1 PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(file1 core)
```

FILE2 CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.7)

project (file2)

set(SOURCES src/file2.cpp src/main.cpp)

add_executable(file2 ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(file2 PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(file2 core)
```

Core CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(core STATIC core.h)
include_directories(core.h)
target_include_directories(core PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

I`m trying to include `core.h` into `file1.h` and `file2.h`.

When I build this I get this errors:
`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\Core\Debug\core.lib' [\blah\blah\build\file1\file1.vcxproj]` and
`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\Core\Debug\core.lib' [\blah\blah\build\file2\file2.vcxproj]`

What am I doing incorrectly?

I do not know what to do

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create STATIC directories purely from header files. Change to an INTERFACE library.

Since you used the PUBLIC modifier when setting `core`'s include directories, linking the `file1` and `file2` targets to `core` will automatically set the include directories, so you need neither the `target_include_directories` or `target_link_directories` commands.